# How do I add a word to the middle of a table in python?

Tags: python

I wrote code that prints an empty 20x20 table. The main goal is to eventually make a program that creates a crossword. I'm trying to figure out how to add a word to the exact center of the board. This is the code I have for printing the table.

```
board = [[' '] * 20 for i in range(20)] 
def addFirstWord(board, word):
    columns = '01234567890123456789'
    rows = '_' * 20
    print(' ' + columns)
    print(' ' + rows)
    for i in range(20):
        s = ''.join(board[i])
        print('|' + s +'|' + str(i))
    print(' ' + rows)
    print(' ' + columns)
```

This is the expected output if I use hippopotamus as the word in the function parameters:
[image: This is the expected output if I use hippopotamus as the word]

Comment: Functions and variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. `addFirstWord` -> `add_first_word`. What does your code currently output, what’s the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a 2D array to hold your values.

A `-` represents an empty square in this sample `5x5` matrix.

```
- - - - -
- F O O -
- - - - -
- - - - -
```

This can be represented in code as an array of 5 arrays of 5 elements each.

So if the table above is stored in the variable `table`, I could access the F with `table[1][1]`, the first `O` with table[1][2]`, etc.

You can generate an empty table first, and then add words by inserting them at the proper spot and replacing the character at that spot in the table.

Comment: He's printing the table. I'm talking about generating a table and then using that pre-built 2D array and replacing characters in the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly center right? But if you want to print at row 10, you may edit your code as follows:

```
board = [[' '] * 20 for i in range(20)] 
def addFirstWord(board, word):
    columns = '01234567890123456789'
    rows = '_' * 20
    print(' ' + columns)
    print(' ' + rows)
    for i in range(20):
        if i != 10:
          s = ''.join(board[i])
          print('|' + s +'|' + str(i))
        else:
          length = int((20-len(word))/2)
          if len(word)%2 == 0:
            print('|'+length*" " + word + length*" "+'|10')
          else:
             print('|'+length*" " + word + length*" "+' |10')
    print(' ' + rows)
    print(' ' + columns)

addFirstWord(board,"hippo")
```

Output:

```
 01234567890123456789
 ____________________
|                    |0
|                    |1
|                    |2
|                    |3
|                    |4
|                    |5
|                    |6
|                    |7
|                    |8
|                    |9
|       hippo        |10
|                    |11
|                    |12
|                    |13
|                    |14
|                    |15
|                    |16
|                    |17
|                    |18
|                    |19
 ____________________
 01234567890123456789
```

Do note that the word will always be biased towards left depending on whether it's even or odd. It's also biased to row 10.